# Which Platform for Unity Server Programming?

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, game-engine

Now I'm developing simple network game with unity c#.
Please give me some advise.

- My Condition

  - I have limited time to develop server (less than 2 weeks)
  - I'm fluent at JAVA and c#.
  - I'm new to game server programming.
- Requirement

  - Concurrent users with local network (~ 10), latency is not a problem
  - Shooting game (enemy's movment and user's status has to be tracked with real time)
- Possible Solution

  1. start from nothing (eg. websocket server with JAVA(spring) or csharp) - this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502317/building-a-simple-online-game-server-for-unity) will be good start point
  2. unity-multiplay : I tested it, and easy. but don't know how exactly work.
  3. other platform such as photon engine(https://www.photonengine.com/en/OnPremise)

Any comment will be welcome to me. Thank you.

Comment: I think using UNET is your best shot considering the short period of time. You'd take maybe a day or two to get the basics.

Comment: I tried one tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovUnNJlREIk&list=PLwyZdDTyvucw5JhBMJxFwsYc1EbQYxr0G). Are there other good tutorials that I can try?

Comment: Unity docs is something to begin with. All online tutorials are just a redo of the Unity docs. https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking

Comment: Do you need to run your custom code on the server? If you only need to sync your players and their actions, Photon Cloud will improve your dev-time a lot. Any other case, UNET will fit your needs at no cost.